# How to check if all corresponding elements of three 2D arrays are zero?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am calculating Green leaf index of an image. Image has been read by opencv and has three bands (RGB). Background has already been removed and now image has only green pixels. I want to calculate the index but when all corresponding elements in all the bands are zero, the formula results in nan values `gli = (2 * g - r - b) / (2 * g + r + b)`.

I want to perform a if block to skip the calculation if all corresponding values are zero.But I want to exclude the scenario where nan values would result.
I am thinking it can be done by checking if r,g,b have corresponding
zero values, if yes then don't perform the calculation. I can't
figure out how to do it.

Following is my code:

```py
# Import libraries 
import numpy as np
from plantcv import plantcv as pcv
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import glob
from skimage import io, img_as_float, img_as_float32, img_as_ubyte, img_as_float64

folder = r"D:\Data\Koochia_Summer_trial\Output\Segmented green 7 days images\Barns 2021_treated"
gli_list = []


for file in glob.glob(folder + "\*.*"):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    a = pcv.rgb2gray_lab(rgb_img=img, channel='a')
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(a, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + 
                                            cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
          
    img_arr = img_as_float32(img)
    r = img_arr[:,:,2]
    b = img_arr[:, :, 0]
    g = img_arr[:,:,1]
            
    np.seterr(invalid='ignore') 
    gr = g/(r+g+b)
    bl = b/(r+g+b)
    re = r/(r+g+b)
                       
    gli = (2 * g - r - b) / (2 * g + r + b)
    gxi = (2*gr) - re-b
            
    gli_no_nan = np.nan_to_num(gli,0,posinf = 1, neginf = 0)
    gxi_no_nan = np.nan_to_num(gxi,0,posinf = 1, neginf = 0)
                    
    average_gli = gli_no_nan[np.nonzero(gli_no_nan)].mean()
    average_gxi = gxi_no_nan[np.nonzero(gxi_no_nan)].mean()
        
    gli_list.append(average_gli) `
```

Comment: You can test if r=g=b=0 with `np.sum(img, axis=2)` if that's what you mean...

Comment: "read by opencv and has three bands (RGB)" -- Actually, it's BGR. It seems that later in the code you've realized that's the case, but the two lines (of apparently dead code) immediately following `imread` produce incorrect result (you fed BGR to function converting from RGB to Lab).

Comment: Seems to me you don't really need a 2D image for this algorithm, just a list of (BGR) triples. So, reshape (`flat = img.reshape(-1,3)`), find which triples are all zeros (`mask = (np.sum(flat, dtype=np.int32, axis=1) != 0)`) and use that mask to filter out all the triples you don't want (`colors = flat[mask]`). Then do the rest of the processing without having to worry about division by zero. | BTW, you might want to cache the result of `(r+g+b)` -- right now you recalculate it 4 times in a row.